# Picasso, image loading and resizing

Tags: android, performance, picasso

I have a lot of images in my app, i am using `resize` and customising the width and height for many of the lists, i am getting large sized images for all of them from server. Is it a good idea to use `resize` or should i get smaller images from the server, wherever is needed, and remove `resize()` from picasso call, will this increase app performance. My main question is, does using `resize` a lot in your app reduces performance as it need to resize every image in your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Picasso` will only `resize()` the image once because it will be cached (specifically stored in the [LruCache](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache)) unless the cache reached the maximum limit your cache will remove an image so that it can store new ones. Accessing the deleted image again will trigger another `resize()` call but for those image that are still in cache Picasso will not need to perform a `resize()`.

If you have a full control to your server it would be better if you can create an API that has customizable image-size-parameter. Let say you only need a thumbnail image therefore you will just provide the width-height of your image rather than downloading a large image which do not give benefits on thumbnails plus you save some bandwidth.

Comment: getting smaller images from server and cutting down resize from picasso call, won't that be a better approach ? will it improve performance and or have no effect ?

Comment: Yes it will but doing this 2 approach is too overkill (Pick only one), The better approach is my second suggestion if you have access to your server code.

Comment: **Conclusion**: The lesser the data you transmit the faster the transaction is.

Comment: Nice, i guess i missed the alternative earlier.Thank you :)

Comment: Your Welcome buddy.

Answer (score 2):

@gurvinder, there seems lot of scenario regarding performance improvement

**Scenario 1 high-resolution image -> large image size -> take longer time to load**

Solution - you can reduce the resolution of image according to your app max resolution support

**Scenario 2 Which Image Library ? Picasso,Glide,UniversalImageLoader or Fresco**
Solution - i suggest you to go with fresco, for me fresco is impressive. caching and performance is much faster than any acc. to me.

Comment: have tried picasso, Aquery and glide so far, liked picasso. will try fresco now :) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this for specify image height and width

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
             .load(uri).resize(100, 100).centerCrop()
             .placeholder(R.drawable.type_pic)
             .error(R.drawable.type_pic)
             .into(holder.icon);
```

Comment: i am using this kind of code, but my question is, will using this resizing a lot effect performance of the app?

Answer (score 1):

Picasso's resize() helps in rendering performance ,

however if the actual file size is big , the downloading time will be more compared with the downloading time of actual size would take.

So go with resized images from server , or if you cannot have resized images for every resolution , use both methods .

By that you can atleast reduce the loading time to considerable time.